# How to left align labels in the bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, pdftex, biber

I'm using `biber` with `PDFLaTeX`, and if references are bigger then 9, in my references page I get references like this:

```
References:
 [1]    ref .........................
 [2]    ref ..........................
 [3]    ref ..........................
 [4]    ref ..........................
 [5]    ref ..........................
 [6]    ref ..........................
 [7]    ref ..........................
 [8]    ref ..........................
 [9]    ref ..........................
[10]    ref ..........................
```

However, I want them to appear like this:

```
References:
[1]    ref .........................
[2]    ref ..........................
[3]    ref ..........................
[4]    ref ..........................
[5]    ref ..........................
[6]    ref ..........................
[7]    ref ..........................
[8]    ref ..........................
[9]    ref ..........................
[10]   ref ..........................
```

Here's my MWA (atiflar.bib contains 10 items):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
        natbib=false,
        style=numeric-comp,
        sorting=none]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{atiflar.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

And here's the atiflar.bib as requested(it contains some items with Turkish characters):

```
@article{lorente,
author      = "Wechsatol W., Lorente S., Bejan A.",
title       = "Tree-Shaped Insulated Design for Uniform Distribution of Hot Water Over an Area",
journal     = "Int. J. Heat Mass Transfer",
volume      = "44",
number      = "16",
pages       = "3111--3123",
year        = "2001",
}

@patent{kavur,
author      = "Kavur K. H.",
title       = "Heart Flowerpot",
year        = "2006",
number      = "D518,755",
location    = "U.S. Patent and Trademark Office",
}

@report{ts2478,
author      = "TS 2478",
title       = "Odunun Statik Eğilmede Elastikiyet Modülün Tayini",
institution = "Türk Standartları Enstitüsü",
year        = "1976",
location    = "Ankara"
}

@article{lorente2,
author      = "Wechsatol, W. and Lorente, S. and Bejan, A.",
title       = "Tree-Shaped Insulated Design for Uniform Distribution of Hot Water Over an Area",
journal     = "Int. J. Heat Mass Transfer",
doi         = "10.1002/er.907",
}
@book{thermo,
author      = "Tester, Jefferson W. and Modell, Michael",
title       = "Thermodynamics and Its Applications",
year        = "1997",
edition     = "3"
}
@inbook{burton1995,
title       = "Sediment Toxicity Testing",
author      = "Burton Jr, G Allen and Denton, Debra L",
booktitle   = "Handbook of ecotoxicology",
edition     = "3",
pages       = "111--151",
year        = "1995",
publisher   = "CRC Press, New York",
editor      = "Hoffman, D. J. and Rattner, B. A. and Burton, G. A"
}
@conference{bilgin2006,
author      = "Bilgin, A. and Mendi, A. and Yağcı, Ç.",
title       = "Esnek Gruplar İçeren Polimerik Ftalosiyaninlerin Sentezi ve Karakterizasyonu",
organization= "VI. Kimya Kongresi",
location    = "Kayseri, Türkiye",
date        = "2006-06-24",
}
@mastersthesis{unlu2006,
author      = "Ünlü, M.",
title       = "Anahtarlı Relüktans Makinasının Modellenmesi ve Dinamik Davranışı",
institution = "Kocaeli Üniversitesi, Fen Bilimleri Enstitüsü, Kocaeli",
year        = "2006",
note        = "154848",
}
@report{werner1982,
author      = "Werner, R. W. and Krikorion, O. H.",
title       = "Synfuels from Fusion Using The Tandem Mirror Reactor and a Thermochemical Cycle to Produce Hydrogen",
type        = "",
institution = "Livermore National Laboratory",
year        = "1982",
pages       = "120--150",
note        = "UCID-19311",
}
@online{citingguide,
url         = "http://www.bournemouth.ac.uk/library/using/guide_to_citing.html",
urldate     = "2005-09-10",
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this, I've searched but couldn't find any. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shorter version:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
        style=numeric-comp,
        sorting=none]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{atiflar.bib}

\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{#1\hss}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You just need to define a new bib environment and remove the `\hss` from the `\makelabel` macro.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\pagestyle{empty}
% taken from numeric.bbx
% remove \hss from \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{labelprefix}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\begin{document}
\nocite{aksin,angenendt,baez/article,bertram,doody,gillies,glashow,herrmann,kastenholz,murray}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]